# iOS XYPieChart datasource methods not being triggered

Tags: ios, delegates, protocols

I am trying to implement the XYPieCharts but am currently unable to get it to display. While debugging I placed some log statements in the data source methods but none of these are being fired.

I have included the delegate (not being used) and datasource as such

```
@interface DwinklySalaryViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate,  XYPieChartDelegate, XYPieChartDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet XYPieChart *salaryPieChart;
```

I have also checked that I have linked up this IBOutlet to the XYPieChart element in the Interface Builder. There is no delegate/datasource outlet in the Interface Builder so I have added that programatically as in the demo. This, and the rest of the options are set in the viewDidLoad method of the a view controller that contains the XYPieChart view.

```
[_salaryPieChart setDelegate:self];
[_salaryPieChart setDataSource:self];
```

I have then implemented the required methods for the datasource protocol:

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfSlicesInPieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart
{
    NSLog(@"Number of slices: %d", pieChartSlices.count);
    return pieChartSlices.count;
}

- (CGFloat)pieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart valueForSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSLog(@"Value slice: %d", [[pieChartSlices objectAtIndex:index] intValue]);
    return [[pieChartSlices objectAtIndex:index] intValue];
}

- (UIColor *)pieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart colorForSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSLog(@"Returning %@", [sliceColors objectAtIndex:(index % sliceColors.count)]);
    return [sliceColors objectAtIndex:(index % sliceColors.count)];
}
```

Could anyone tell me what I've missed out that causes the data source methods not to trigger?

Comment: Did you call reloadData in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear?

Comment: @rdelmar Oh I wasn't aware that I had to call that explicitly on the first load. I assumed that a reload was only necessary when updating the initial data. Let me give that a try and report back on how that works out!

Comment: @rdelmar it worked perfectly :) Please add an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that with the way XYPieChart works, you have you call reloadData on it at startup. It works ok in either viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear.